# View source code without permissions

Tags: permissions

Well, I want to read a source code that I didn't create with permissions `rwx------`.

Is there any way to do it?

I don't have permission, of course. Sorry that I didn't mention it but I don't have 
also root privileges.

Finally the computer is remote ,,, (ssh access)

Comment: What sort of access do you have to the system? Can you reboot to a live CD? To single user mode? (I assume you don't have any `sudo` privileges.)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the therminal.
Use the necessary command.  For   example : sudo chmod 754 file.x  .    Wich command? You will find it here : http://catcode.com/teachmod/     (tutorial for chmod)